# C# wrapper for wordpress api

Tags: c#, wordpress

Can anybody suggest me a C# wrapper for the wordpress api, which works good, without any errors or exceptions.

Comment: Do you mean something to let you use the XML-RPC API? That's the only external interface WordPress supports, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried JoeBlogs? http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have used this api, i tried this one but its giving me exceptions. Can u help me out with the code ?

Comment: Sorry for not developing it... it's on GitHub now - https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs

Comment: If you're still having trouble please let me know, i'm  currently updating it for wp 3.4 +